# Google Structured Data needs "lowPrice" property

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I have some products in website, some of them have price,
but some are inquiry products that without price on page.

Google search console tells me the `lowPrice` property is necessary. How can I mark these products up without price?

> [image: Missing: lowprice]

Here is the sample code:

```html
<tr itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<td><a itemprop="url" href="#"><img src="#.png" itemprop="image" class="ProdImg"></a></td>
<td><a href="#">KOA</a></td>
<td itemprop="description"><a href="#">name</a></td>
<td><a itemprop="url" href="#"><span itemprop="name">HV731JTTD1002F</span></a></td>
<td itemprop="description">HV73</td>
<td class="price"><a href="#">inquiry</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the Microdata that gives this error? [`lowPrice`](http://schema.org/lowPrice) is from `AggregateOffer`, but you don’t seem to have this item.

Comment: oh! I got it. 'AggregateOffer' is in the other part of the page. I missed some code there.

By the way, Is there any micordata prop means "I have 320 products in this category"? the html is like that:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2j9k4r4x/

Comment: Judging from the snippet in your question as well as the snippet in your JSFiddle, it seems that you aren’t using Microdata correctly: having several `description`/`name`/`url` properties in the same `itemscope` is technically allowed, but it only makes sense if all of these are about this item -- but using it, e.g., for different categories like that is not appropriate.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the (minimal!) HTML5+Microdata that gives the error your question is about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schema.org AggregateRating markup when ratingValue is Empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32803838/schema-org-aggregaterating-markup-when-ratingvalue-is-empty)