# Schema.org AggregateRating markup when ratingValue is Empty

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I am implementing structured data into an app with the [AggregateRating markup](http://schema.org/AggregateRating). The problem is that when 0 ratings are present the rating value is empty. I get the following error when using Google Structured Data Testing Tool.

> Field ratingValue may not be empty.

```
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
<meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="0">
<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="">
...
</div>
```

The app uses the default 1 to 5 rating scale.

Is there a default value that complies with Schema.org that can be passed to when the `ratingValue` is empty? I don't want to pass it an arbitrary number on the scale just to avoid the error...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Google Structured Data Testing Tool error you quote is misleading. It’s *not* an error with your use of Schema.org or Microdata.

Instead it just means that Google probably won’t consider displaying their [Aggregate Ratings Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews#aggregate_ratings) for your document in Google Search (naturally, because a rating value would be required for this).

However, providing the empty string as value for the `ratingValue` property doesn’t really make sense here. So why not simply omit the property? And ideally you would omit the `aggregateRating` property with the `AggregateRating` altogether if you don’t have any reviews yet.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you see any issues passing ratingValue of 1 and a reviewCount 0 ?

Comment: @JeffD23: I have no experience with this; in such cases, I’ve always omitted generating the properties. But I guess nothing bad should happen (if you really want to have a rating of 1 in case of no reviews yet).

Comment: The SDTT recently recommends including aggregateRating for Products. Which is a bit annoying when they don't show what to do if there are no reviews. I personally exclude the aggregateRating when there are no reviews, and now get the warnings.

Comment: Also google added warnings on products (new report) to google search console when there are no rating.