# How to handle no Reviews for Google Structured Data Testing Tool

Tags: html, microdata, google-rich-snippets

My HTML content has reviews data and so I am wrapping it in a div which has itemtype and itemscope attributes defined, telling the browser it uses HTML5 Microdata. But how should I handle the scenario when there are no reviews (for example a new product in my store doesn't have any reviews submitted for it yet).

Right now I am doing something like this...

```
 <div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate">
  <meta itemprop="count" content="0 Reviews">
  <meta itemprop="rating" content="0.0">
    There are no reviews for this item.
</div>
```

A simple message for the user saying there are no reviews, and a couple of meta tags telling the Bot the same.

But Google's Structured Data Testing Tool complains for this saying....

"Failed to normalize the rating value.
Your rating value was out of the default range, you must provide best and worst values."

And if I leave rating out altogether then it complains saying rating is "missing and required".

How can I make it happy in the case when there are no reviews for my content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Review-aggregate` type](http://www.data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate) represents "a review of a business, product or organization". You don’t have a review. So you should not use this type at all.

```html
<div>
  There are no reviews for this item.
</div>
```

By the way, unless you have a specific reason for using Data-Vocabulary.org, you might want to use Schema.org instead (or in addition). Data-Vocabulary.org is no longer maintained. The [advice stays the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32804039/1591669): don’t use a type if you don’t have the thing this type represents.