# 'aggregateRating' and 'review' for products that don't have any ratings or reviews

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I am adding `aggregateRating` and `review` properties to my new product pages that don't have any ratings or reviews. How would I add them to my pages and have them be valid for Google Structured Data?

```html
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="">
    <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="">
</div>

<meta itemprop="review" content="">
```

I need to know what to put in for the content of not having established a value yet with the products being so new.

Comment: See also: [Schema.org AggregateRating markup when ratingValue is Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32803838/1591669)

Comment: You can completely exclude the aggregateRating. The SDTT will give a warning that it is recommended, but it is not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the Schema specification for the type **[AggregateRating](https://schema.org/AggregateRating)**, there you will find the following information:

> The average rating based on **multiple** ratings or reviews.

The same thing tells us **[Technical guidelines of Google for Review](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet#technical-guidelines)**:

> Make sure to mark up an aggregate evaluation of an item by **many people** with schema.org/AggregateRating.

In both cases, the plural is mentioned (highlighted by me), that is, your product must have at least two reviews. Probably you may be useful advice Tony McCreath which he mentions in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Google said, AggregateRating or Review or Offers are now required.
If you don't provide it on /Product, It will result an error.

https://yoast.com/help/aggregaterating-review-offer-required/

If you get reviews or ratings on some products, push empty value when its empty to avoid error penalty. Theese products will not be pushed on google search anyway.

If you never have review or rating, you have to use /offers in your /Product :
https://schema.org/offers